# Problema de codificación al recuperar un dump de mi base de datos remota en Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, codificación

He hecho un dump de mi base de datos remota (MySQL) y al descargar el archivo del servidor en mi equipo local (Mac OS X) estoy teniendo problemas con los acentos y caracteres especiales.

En el servidor el archivo se crea con la extensión `.gz`, en el Mac yo extraigo el archivo a `.sql` y cuando lo abro (he probado en varios editores) los caracteres especiales no son reconocidos.

Un ejemplo:

> Les dijo Jes√∫s: "Yo soy el pan de la vida. El que venga a m√≠, no
> tendr√° hambre, y el que crea en m√≠, no tendr√° nunca sed"

En un equipo basado en Linux no tengo este problema, yo extraigo el archivo y al abrirlo se ve correctamente:

> Les dijo Jesús: "Yo soy el pan de la vida. El que venga a mí, no
> tendrá hambre, y el que crea en mí, no tendrá nunca sed"

Para extraer el `.gz` he usado tanto Archive Utility como el comando `gunzip` en la Terminal y en ambos casos ocurre el mismo problema. Descarto que sea problema del archivo comprimido, dado que en Linux funciona.

Por si era un problema en la codificación del dump, he agregado esto en el comando: `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` y nada de nada (originalmente las tablas están en `utf8`).

He probado incluso a pasar el archivo descomprimido en Linux (el cual se ve correctamente allí) al Mac, y en el Mac ese archivo que en Linux se ve bien, tiene el mismo problema.

He probado varios editores: Nova, TextEdit, Vim (desde la Terminal), y en todos ocurre lo mismo.

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema en Mac?

Comment: Tal vez usar [`iconv`](https://ss64.com/osx/iconv.html) sobre el fichero sea de utilidad. Algo como `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac input.sql > output.sql`

Comment: @MauricioContreras ¿dónde pondría eso, en la instrucción al crear el dump? Es curioso que al abrir el archivo en mi IDE de base de datos (DBeaver) sí me ha reconocido los caracteres correctamente. Pero al ser un archivo muy grande va lentísimo, yo quería editarlo en Nova el cual trabaja más rápido con archivos grandes.

Comment: En la terminal de macOS. Es una utilidad de terminal.

Comment: @A.Cedano te buscan por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136425/stack-overflow-en-espanol-mysql)

Comment: En el terminal de Mac supongo que puedes hacer un `file nombrearchivodescomprimido` para ver que codificación tiene y a partir de ahí sacar tus conclusiones.  Yo me inclino porque tu editor no soporta la codificación que tenga o quizas alguna de las tablas de tu base de datos es la que causa toda esa corrupción y si haces exportaciones más pequeñas (unas cuantas tablas cada vez) puedas encontrar la que da problemas.

Comment: El terminal de Mac tiene en común los comandos de Linux ya que su sistema se basa en el sistema de Linux pero solo los comandos.

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias a tu sugerencia he encontrado el problema. He publicado una respuesta para explicar el proceso.

Comment: @masterguru era precisamente eso, una de las tablas estaba metiendo basura en el dump, gracias a `iconv` pude ubicar ese contenido basura y darme cuenta de que esa tabla (que fue instalada por un antiguo plugin) estaba pululando en mi BD.

Comment: Perfecto, estaba mirando tu respuesta... eso me da que pensar que quizás las tablas con datos binarios pueden causar esa corruptela de codificación de datos... ¿cual era el tipo de datos de la primera columna de esa tabla? binary?  varbinary?

Comment: @masterguru era del tipo `binary(16)`. Esa tabla la instaló un antiguo plugin de seguridad y tenía un montón de contenido de ese estilo... Cuando desinstalé el plugin la tabla se quedó ahí y si no es por este error ni me entero. Ahora estoy revisando todas las tablas para quitar posible contenido basura.

Comment: vale, segun leo por ahí, hay un parámetro de **mysldump** que quizás hubiera podido evitar ese problema:  `--hex-blob, Dump binary columns using hexadecimal notation.` pero no puedo asegurártelo pues no tengo tablas con ese tipo de datos para probar.  O quizás tu tabla estaba corrupta por otros motivos o conversiones anteriores o del script que almacenaba los datos que quizás forzaba algo mal mientras los guardaba (pero luego era capaz de leerlos supongo).

Comment: No he probado con esa opción @masterguru porque para este caso no me interesaba recuperar esos datos. Creo que esa tabla estaba destinada a capturar ataques de fuerza bruta con contenido binario o algo así.

Comment: Si si, entiendo, gracias. Bueno, de todas formas me lo anoto mentalmente por si acaso surge una pregunta similar para decirselo al OP que lo pruebe.

Answer (score 2):

[El comentario de @MauricioContreras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537111/problema-de-codificaci%C3%B3n-al-recuperar-un-dump-de-mi-base-de-datos-remota-en-mac?noredirect=1#comment951600_537111) me ha puesto en la ruta correcta para resolver el problema.

Al ejecutar en Terminal:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac archivoFuente.sql > archivoDestino.sql
```

Ha ocurrido un error:

> iconv: archivoFuente.sql:4863:72: cannot convert

Al abrir el archivo e ir a la línea `4863` había en esa línea contenido con caracteres raros que eran los que estaban causando el problema.

```
 -- Dumping data for table `laTablaAntigua`
 --
 
 LOCK TABLES `laTablaAntigua` WRITE; /*!40000 ALTER TABLE
 `laTablaAntigua` DISABLE KEYS */; INSERT INTO `laTablaAntigua` VALUES
 (_binary '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇπV§n','TR',2,18023,'brute'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇQ´í','NL',1,17993,'brute'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇÿ¨†g','US',6,17997,'waf'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇ-?L\€','US',6,17997,'waf'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇπV\r\’','TR',1,17997,'brute'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇtÀä','DE',3,17997,'waf'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇê\Ÿ|','CA',6,17997,'waf'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇ¿Òºı','US',6,17998,'waf'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇπV§n','TR',1,17998,'brute'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇ/`9','CN',1,18000,'brute'),(_binary
 '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ˇˇπQù\…','FR',3,18000,'waf'),
 ....
```

Ese contenido venía de una tabla que había instalado un antiguo plugin de seguridad en mi base de datos, y esa tabla no se borró cuando desinstalé el plugin.

**La solución ha sido borrar esa tabla que estaba metiendo basura en el dump** y ahora todo funciona bien, ni siquiera necesito hacer `iconv`, en el nuevo dump puedo abrir el archivo extraído directamente y todo se ve correcto.

Me alegro del error, porque me ayudó a detectar un contenido no deseado en mi base de datos.